# Enter Unique entry through array_push function

Tags: php, arrays

```
 <?php
   $productid = $_POST['pid'];
   array_push($ids,$productid);
 ?>
```

I want to push unique entry into my array.If `$productid` is the `id` which is already exist in `array($ids)` then it can't store into `array($ids)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array) check before adding that to your array.

```
<?php
   $productid = $_POST['pid'];
   if(!in_array($productid,$ids))
   {
       array_push($ids,$productid);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!in_array($_POST['pid'], $ids)){
 $ids[] = $_POST['pid'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
<?php
   $productid = $_POST['pid'];
if(!(inarray($productid,$ids)))
{
   array_push($ids,$productid);
}
 ?>
```